# why this closure and IIFE dont works?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

Why this code dont print `i` and `j` variables?

```
(function f() {
  let i = 1;
  let j = 2;
  return () => {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(j);
  }
})()
```

I know, i know... this code yes, works:

```
let f = () => {
  let i = 1;
  let j = 2;
  return () => {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(j);
  }
}

f()();
```

Yes, the last code works, but I what to know why the first code doesn't works

Thanks a lot

Comment: The first code sample only makes one function call, the call to `f()`.  It does not call the function returned from `f()`.

Comment: You still need the extra pair of parentheses `(function f() { ... })()()`

Comment: Reason why the first one is not working it is because you are returning a function from IIFE which is not invoked LATER so if you try to add 1 more () after 

(function f() {
  //
})()()

It will return the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a function (`return () => {}`) from the function but not calling it. You could simply just `log` the values in the function without returning a new function.

```js
(function f() {
  let i = 1;
  let j = 2;
  console.log(i);
  console.log(j);
})();
```

Or call it like this.

```js
(function f() {
  let i = 1;
  let j = 2;
  return () => {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(j);
  }
})()();
```

Comment: @mplungjan upon its initial posting the second sample was not present. It's all good now.